# Problem of slowing down when learning a single gpu using multiple gpus enviroment

Tags: python, deep-learning

I want to do deep learning with single gpu at multiple gpus environment.
My computer have 4 gpus, and i set to train train.py at each gpu.

I typed at four different command window like below:

```
"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 train.py"
"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1 train.py"
"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2 train.py"
"CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=3 train.py"
```

It had some speed problem.
Each train.py was conducted at a different pace, I don't know the reason.
only one train.py was so fastest.
the slowest thing didn't learn anything during 12 hours.

How can I solve it so that all train.py have the same speed?